# Java applet VOIP audiostream merge, gives choppy sound

Tags: java, applet, voip, audio-streaming

I am trying to write a VOIP conference Java Applet. Everything is working smoothly with good sound quality, untill a 3rd user enters the room. I'm trying to merge the several audio streams, but when its done the sound is really choppy. Every stream comes in on a different thread.
The more users logg onto the applet the bigger the quality loss.

Audioformat:  Sampling rate : 8000,  Bits: 16

this is where a single audiostream comes in:

```
while (true) {
                DatagramPacket receive = new DatagramPacket(mBuffer, mBuffer.length);
                datagramSocket.receive(receive);
                System.out.println("Received from: " + receive.getAddress() + ":" + receive.getPort());
                short[] shortBuffer = convert(mBuffer); // Convert the buffer to a 2byte short

                double volume = calcVolume(calcDistance(Client.getUser().getXPosition(), Client.getUser().getYPosition(), mUser.getXPosition(), mUser.getYPosition())); // Used to calculate sound for proximity effect
                for (int i = 0; i < shortBuffer.length; i++) {
                    shortBuffer[i] *= volume;
                }
                mBuffer = convert(shortBuffer);

                position = 0; // Set the short position in the buffer to 0
                //resetPosition();
            }
```

This is where the audio streams come together and get merged:

```
    class PlayThread extends Thread {
    private short[] previousBuffer; // Used to prevent from duplicated data
    private short[] buffer = new short[1];

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            previousBuffer = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                int sum = 0;
                int total = 0;

                synchronized (mReceiveThreads) {
                    for (ReceiveThread receiveThread : mReceiveThreads) {
                        short[] sBuffer = convert(receiveThread.mBuffer);

                        buffer = smoothArray(sBuffer, 1.6); // Smooth the current buffer
                        if (receiveThread.position < sBuffer.length) {
                            sum += sBuffer[receiveThread.position];
                            receiveThread.position++;
                            total++;
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (total > 0) {
                    buffer[i] = (short) (sum / total);
                }

            }

            if(!Arrays.equals(buffer, previousBuffer)) {

                //lowerVolume();
                if(ClientPanel.getAudioselected()) {
                    sourceDataLine.write(convert(buffer), 0, buffer.length * 2);
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("Took " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + "ns.");
        }
    }
```

As you can see I loop through all of my receivethreads and get 1 short from all of them. I get the average sound and write the output to the sourcedataline.

Any ideas how to prevent the sound from getting so choppy?

Comment: What do you do to make sure you have new audio from all sources before creating the output?  Ideally, there'd be some sort of jitter buffer as well...